# How to update code that uses deprecated each()

Tags: php, each, deprecated

I'm trying to update a piece of old code (a menu builder class). I've updated everything else but I'm stuck at a line that uses the each() function. I did read some of the previous threads but this particular instance is too complex for me to figure out how to change. Here it is:

```
while ( $loop && ( ( $option = each( $children[$parent] ) ) || ( $parent > $root_id ) ) )
```

This is the entire function where the above line occurs:

```
function get_menu_html($lang, $root_id = 0 )
{
    $this->html  = array();
    $this->items = $this->get_menu_items($lang);
    
    foreach ( $this->items as $item )
        $children[$item['sectionParentID']][] = $item;
    
    // loop will be false if the root has no children (i.e., an empty menu!)
    $loop = !empty( $children[$root_id] );
    
    // initializing $parent as the root
    $parent = $root_id;
    $parent_stack = array();
    
    // HTML wrapper for the menu (open)
    $this->html[] = '<ul>';
    
    while ( $loop && ( ( $option = each( $children[$parent] ) ) || ( $parent > $root_id ) ) )
    {
        if ( $option === false )
        {
            $parent = array_pop( $parent_stack );
            
            // HTML for menu item containing children (close)
            $this->html[] = str_repeat( "\t", ( count( $parent_stack ) + 1 ) * 2 ) . '</ul>';
            $this->html[] = str_repeat( "\t", ( count( $parent_stack ) + 1 ) * 2 - 1 ) . '</li>';
        }
        elseif ( !empty( $children[$option['value']['sectionID']] ) )
        {
            $tab = str_repeat( "\t", ( count( $parent_stack ) + 1 ) * 2 - 1 );
            
            // HTML for menu item containing children (open)
            $this->html[] = sprintf(
                '%1$s<li><a href="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
                $tab,   // %1$s = tabulation
                $option['value']['sectionPage'],   // %2$s = sectionPage (URL)
                $option['value']['sectionLabel']   // %3$s = title
            ); 
            $this->html[] = $tab . "\t" . '<ul class="submenu">';
            
            array_push( $parent_stack, $option['value']['sectionParentID'] );
            $parent = $option['value']['sectionID'];
        }
        else
            // HTML for menu item with no children (aka "leaf") 
            $this->html[] = sprintf(
                '%1$s<li><a href="%2$s">%3$s</a></li>',
                str_repeat( "\t", ( count( $parent_stack ) + 1 ) * 2 - 1 ),   // %1$s = tabulation
                $option['value']['sectionPage'],   // %2$s = sectionPage (URL)
                $option['value']['sectionLabel']   // %3$s = title
            );
    }
```

EDIT: Adding screenshots to show what this code and the two suggestions below produce.

ORIGINAL (with the deprecated each() function):
[image]

Josh's version:
[image]

Kevin Y's version:
[image]

EDIT 2: Here is a print out of what I get from my DB using `get_menu_items($lang)` if you want to test it with my own data:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [sectionID] => 1 [sectionParentID] => 0 [sectionPage] => Home [sectionLabel] => Начало ) [1] => Array ( [sectionID] => 2 [sectionParentID] => 0 [sectionPage] => Translations [sectionLabel] => Преvоди ) [2] => Array ( [sectionID] => 3 [sectionParentID] => 0 [sectionPage] => Prose [sectionLabel] => Проzа ) [3] => Array ( [sectionID] => 4 [sectionParentID] => 0 [sectionPage] => Poetry [sectionLabel] => Поезiя ) [4] => Array ( [sectionID] => 5 [sectionParentID] => 3 [sectionPage] => Stories [sectionLabel] => Разкази ) [5] => Array ( [sectionID] => 6 [sectionParentID] => 3 [sectionPage] => Articles [sectionLabel] => Статии ) [6] => Array ( [sectionID] => 7 [sectionParentID] => 3 [sectionPage] => Essays [sectionLabel] => Есета ) [7] => Array ( [sectionID] => 8 [sectionParentID] => 3 [sectionPage] => Fragments [sectionLabel] => Фрагменти ) [8] => Array ( [sectionID] => 9 [sectionParentID] => 4 [sectionPage] => Woman [sectionLabel] => Аз и Жената ) [9] => Array ( [sectionID] => 10 [sectionParentID] => 4 [sectionPage] => Civilization [sectionLabel] => Аз и Цивилизацията ) [10] => Array ( [sectionID] => 11 [sectionParentID] => 4 [sectionPage] => Universe [sectionLabel] => Аз и Вселената ) [11] => Array ( [sectionID] => 12 [sectionParentID] => 4 [sectionPage] => Duskoreznitsa [sectionLabel] => (По-)Етична дъскорезница ) [12] => Array ( [sectionID] => 13 [sectionParentID] => 4 [sectionPage] => PrazniPrikazki [sectionLabel] => Празни приказки ) [13] => Array ( [sectionID] => 14 [sectionParentID] => 4 [sectionPage] => Extrakts [sectionLabel] => Екстракти ) [14] => Array ( [sectionID] => 17 [sectionParentID] => 0 [sectionPage] => Blog [sectionLabel] => Трънки и блогинkи ) [15] => Array ( [sectionID] => 18 [sectionParentID] => 0 [sectionPage] => Contact [sectionLabel] => Контакт ) [16] => Array ( [sectionID] => 19 [sectionParentID] => 0 [sectionPage] => About [sectionLabel] => За сайта ) [17] => Array ( [sectionID] => 20 [sectionParentID] => 3 [sectionPage] => Research [sectionLabel] => Изследвания ) [18] => Array ( [sectionID] => 21 [sectionParentID] => 3 [sectionPage] => Amsterdamned [sectionLabel] => Amsterdamned ) [19] => Array ( [sectionID] => 22 [sectionParentID] => 4 [sectionPage] => Treski [sectionLabel] => Трески ) [20] => Array ( [sectionID] => 23 [sectionParentID] => 2 [sectionPage] => PoetryTranslation [sectionLabel] => Преводи на поезия ) [21] => Array ( [sectionID] => 25 [sectionParentID] => 2 [sectionPage] => ProseTranslation [sectionLabel] => Преводи на проза ) [22] => Array ( [sectionID] => 27 [sectionParentID] => 2 [sectionPage] => SubtitleTranslation [sectionLabel] => Преводи на субтитри ) [23] => Array ( [sectionID] => 28 [sectionParentID] => 2 [sectionPage] => OpinionJournalismTranslation [sectionLabel] => Преводи на публицистика ) )
```

`parent_id` is replaced with `sectionParentID`
`id` is replaced with `sectionID`
`link` is replaced with `sectionPage`
`title` is replaced with `sectionLabel`.

Comment: if you run the code does it still indicate deprecated?

Comment: Can you post a minimalist isolated example of the function, an example input and its output using "each"? The loop is rather complicated how it iterates using each and playing around with its parent, and can be a bunch of spaghetti. Ideally this could be refactored to something more human readable like looping over the parents first so a loop can be constructed that is more fluid so it's less complicated for a human to figure out. In an isolated example, you could give us the whole function.

Comment: @Dean: Yes, I see this message: "Deprecated: The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls in C:..."

Comment: @KevinY: I struggle to understand this function really. If I knew exactly what it does, I might have been able to write a new one to the same effect.

Comment: @cheeseus can you grab the output of `$this->items = $this->get_menu_items($lang);` using something like print_r and an exit? Then based on the output (no need to show us your production data), provide an isolated example input we can play around with?

Comment: @KevinY, Please find the original code in this post (I got it from somewhere else, can't find it now): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892308/php-generate-menu-from-database-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, if you need to move away from `each($ar)` you can usually use `[key($ar),current($ar)]` as a drop in replacement but then you need to move the pointer within the loop. You usually just need to call `next($ar)` within the loop and break once you run out of reading room such as breaking when the key is null. Then just make sure the array becomes set to false when it runs out of room.

This type of approach can get ugly very quickly though due to the extra code...

So without really paying much attention to your code, after this update, your revised code would like look:

```
function get_menu_html($lang, $root_id = 0 )
{
    $this->html  = array();
    $this->items = $this->get_menu_items($lang);
    
    foreach ( $this->items as $item )
        $children[$item['sectionParentID']][] = $item;
    
    // loop will be false if the root has no children (i.e., an empty menu!)
    $loop = !empty( $children[$root_id] );
    
    // initializing $parent as the root
    $parent = $root_id;
    $parent_stack = array();
    
    // HTML wrapper for the menu (open)
    $this->html[] = '<ul>';
    
    while ( $loop && ( ( $option = [key($children[$parent]),current($children[$parent])] ) || ( $parent > $root_id ) ) )
    {
        if($option[0] === null){$option = false;} // replicate each's behavior for after last element
        next($children[$parent]);
        if ( $option === false )
        {
            $parent = array_pop( $parent_stack );
            
            // HTML for menu item containing children (close)
            $this->html[] = str_repeat( "\t", ( count( $parent_stack ) + 1 ) * 2 ) . '</ul>';
            $this->html[] = str_repeat( "\t", ( count( $parent_stack ) + 1 ) * 2 - 1 ) . '</li>';
            break;
        }
        elseif ( !empty( $children[$option['value']['sectionID']] ) )
        {
            $tab = str_repeat( "\t", ( count( $parent_stack ) + 1 ) * 2 - 1 );
            
            // HTML for menu item containing children (open)
            $this->html[] = sprintf(
                '%1$s<li><a href="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
                $tab,   // %1$s = tabulation
                $option['value']['sectionPage'],   // %2$s = sectionPage (URL)
                $option['value']['sectionLabel']   // %3$s = title
            ); 
            $this->html[] = $tab . "\t" . '<ul class="submenu">';
            
            array_push( $parent_stack, $option['value']['sectionParentID'] );
            $parent = $option['value']['sectionID'];
        }
        else
            // HTML for menu item with no children (aka "leaf") 
            $this->html[] = sprintf(
                '%1$s<li><a href="%2$s">%3$s</a></li>',
                str_repeat( "\t", ( count( $parent_stack ) + 1 ) * 2 - 1 ),   // %1$s = tabulation
                $option['value']['sectionPage'],   // %2$s = sectionPage (URL)
                $option['value']['sectionLabel']   // %3$s = title
            );
    }
```

edit: note the above code doesn't work since it references `$option['value']` from the each rather than `$option[1]` from the each. Will need to adjust that in the code.

You might also want to refactor the code. But getting it working, without the deprecated code, is a good first step.

This type of approach is usually very ugly though. Best to refactor and use a foreach loop of some sort specific to the code's logic.

**Edit:**
Here's an isolated example I'm working on from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892308/php-generate-menu-from-database-table) that was provided to the original code:

```
<?php

/**
 * Generate HTML for multi-dimensional menu from MySQL database
 * with ONE QUERY and WITHOUT RECURSION 
 * @author J. Bruni
 */
class MenuBuilder
{

    /**
     * Menu items
     */
    var $items = array();

    /**
     * HTML contents
     */
    var $html  = array();



    /**
     * Get all menu items from database
     */
    function get_menu_items()
    {
        // Change the field names and the table name in the query below to match tour needs
        return [
                ['id'=>1, 'parent_id'=>0, 'title'=>'title 1','link'=>'link 1','position'=>'0'],
                ['id'=>2, 'parent_id'=>1, 'title'=>'title 2','link'=>'link 2','position'=>'0'],
                ['id'=>3, 'parent_id'=>1, 'title'=>'title 3','link'=>'link 3','position'=>'0'],
                ['id'=>4, 'parent_id'=>0, 'title'=>'title 4','link'=>'link 4','position'=>'0'],
            ];
    }

    /**
     * Build the HTML for the menu 
     */
    function get_menu_html( $root_id = 0 )
    {
        $this->html  = array();
        $this->items = $this->get_menu_items();

        foreach ( $this->items as $item )
            $children[$item['parent_id']][] = $item;

        // loop will be false if the root has no children (i.e., an empty menu!)
        $loop = !empty( $children[$root_id] );

        // initializing $parent as the root
        $parent = $root_id;
        $parent_stack = array();

        // HTML wrapper for the menu (open)
        $this->html[] = '<ul>';

        while ( $loop && ( ( $option = each( $children[$parent] ) ) || ( $parent > $root_id ) ) )
        {
            if ( $option === false )
            {
                $parent = array_pop( $parent_stack );

                // HTML for menu item containing childrens (close)
                $this->html[] = str_repeat( "\t", ( count( $parent_stack ) + 1 ) * 2 ) . '</ul>';
                $this->html[] = str_repeat( "\t", ( count( $parent_stack ) + 1 ) * 2 - 1 ) . '</li>';
            }
            elseif ( !empty( $children[$option['value']['id']] ) )
            {
                $tab = str_repeat( "\t", ( count( $parent_stack ) + 1 ) * 2 - 1 );

                // HTML for menu item containing childrens (open)
                $this->html[] = sprintf(
                    '%1$s<li><a href="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
                    $tab,   // %1$s = tabulation
                    $option['value']['link'],   // %2$s = link (URL)
                    $option['value']['title']   // %3$s = title
                ); 
                $this->html[] = $tab . "\t" . '<ul class="submenu">';

                array_push( $parent_stack, $option['value']['parent_id'] );
                $parent = $option['value']['id'];
            }
            else
                // HTML for menu item with no children (aka "leaf") 
                $this->html[] = sprintf(
                    '%1$s<li><a href="%2$s">%3$s</a></li>',
                    str_repeat( "\t", ( count( $parent_stack ) + 1 ) * 2 - 1 ),   // %1$s = tabulation
                    $option['value']['link'],   // %2$s = link (URL)
                    $option['value']['title']   // %3$s = title
                );
        }

        // HTML wrapper for the menu (close)
        $this->html[] = '</ul>';

        return implode( "\r\n", $this->html );
    }
}

$menu = new MenuBuilder();
echo '<pre>' . $menu->get_menu_html() . '</pre>';



?>
```

It still has "each" in there, but it's isolated so it should be easier to convert over.
Can play with it here: https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Working on getting this converted now...

Here's a drop-in replacement I wrote:

```
    public function each(&$ar)
    {
        $key = key($ar);
        if($key === null){return false;}
        $current = current($ar);
        
        try
        {
        return [$key,$current,'key'=>$key,'value'=>$current];
        }finally{
          next($ar);  
        };
        
    }
```

Then instead of:

```
while ( $loop && ( ( $option = each( $children[$parent] ) ) || ( $parent > $root_id ) ) )
```

use:

```
while ( $loop && ( ( $option = $this->each( $children[$parent] ) ) || ( $parent > $root_id ) ) )
```

i.e. using $this->each instead of each.

Final code:

```
<?php

/**
 * Generate HTML for multi-dimensional menu from MySQL database
 * with ONE QUERY and WITHOUT RECURSION 
 * @author J. Bruni
 */
class MenuBuilder
{

    /**
     * Menu items
     */
    var $items = array();

    /**
     * HTML contents
     */
    var $html  = array();


    public function each(&$ar)
    {
        $key = key($ar);
        if($key === null){return false;}
        $current = current($ar);
        
        try
        {
        return [$key,$current,'key'=>$key,'value'=>$current];
        }finally{
          next($ar);  
        };
        
    }


    /**
     * Get all menu items from database
     */
    function get_menu_items()
    {
        // Change the field names and the table name in the query below to match tour needs
        return [
                ['id'=>1, 'parent_id'=>0, 'title'=>'title 1','link'=>'link 1','position'=>'0'],
                ['id'=>2, 'parent_id'=>1, 'title'=>'title 2','link'=>'link 2','position'=>'0'],
                ['id'=>3, 'parent_id'=>1, 'title'=>'title 3','link'=>'link 3','position'=>'0'],
                ['id'=>4, 'parent_id'=>0, 'title'=>'title 4','link'=>'link 4','position'=>'0'],
            ];
    }

    /**
     * Build the HTML for the menu 
     */
    function get_menu_html( $root_id = 0 )
    {
        $this->html  = array();
        $this->items = $this->get_menu_items();

        foreach ( $this->items as $item )
            $children[$item['parent_id']][] = $item;

        // loop will be false if the root has no children (i.e., an empty menu!)
        $loop = !empty( $children[$root_id] );

        // initializing $parent as the root
        $parent = $root_id;
        $parent_stack = array();

        // HTML wrapper for the menu (open)
        $this->html[] = '<ul>';

        while ( $loop && ( ( $option = $this->each( $children[$parent] ) ) || ( $parent > $root_id ) ) )
        {
            if ( $option === false )
            {
                $parent = array_pop( $parent_stack );

                // HTML for menu item containing childrens (close)
                $this->html[] = str_repeat( "\t", ( count( $parent_stack ) + 1 ) * 2 ) . '</ul>';
                $this->html[] = str_repeat( "\t", ( count( $parent_stack ) + 1 ) * 2 - 1 ) . '</li>';
            }
            elseif ( !empty( $children[$option['value']['id']] ) )
            {
                $tab = str_repeat( "\t", ( count( $parent_stack ) + 1 ) * 2 - 1 );

                // HTML for menu item containing childrens (open)
                $this->html[] = sprintf(
                    '%1$s<li><a href="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
                    $tab,   // %1$s = tabulation
                    $option['value']['link'],   // %2$s = link (URL)
                    $option['value']['title']   // %3$s = title
                ); 
                $this->html[] = $tab . "\t" . '<ul class="submenu">';

                array_push( $parent_stack, $option['value']['parent_id'] );
                $parent = $option['value']['id'];
            }
            else
                // HTML for menu item with no children (aka "leaf") 
                $this->html[] = sprintf(
                    '%1$s<li><a href="%2$s">%3$s</a></li>',
                    str_repeat( "\t", ( count( $parent_stack ) + 1 ) * 2 - 1 ),   // %1$s = tabulation
                    $option['value']['link'],   // %2$s = link (URL)
                    $option['value']['title']   // %3$s = title
                );
        }

        // HTML wrapper for the menu (close)
        $this->html[] = '</ul>';

        return implode( "\r\n", $this->html );
    }
}

$menu = new MenuBuilder();
echo '<pre>' . $menu->get_menu_html() . '</pre>';



?>
```

Tests fine over here:
https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Comment: I tried to directly replace the existing function with your version but the page just exploded with a bunch of errors:

Notice: Undefined index: value in ... line 81, which is 'elseif ( !empty( $children[$option['value']['sectionID']] ) )'

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in ... (same line).

This is repeated over a dozen times. I can't understand what's wrong, sorry.

Comment: @cheeseus replace each of the `$option['value']`'s with `$option[1]` and it should work.

Comment: @cheeseus I added an `each` implementation as a method that would be relatively painless to use, along with future readers. Just call `$this->each(...)` instead of `each(...)` and add my each method to your class.

Comment: Just tested this with my DB connection and it works without any errors. I guess it would have been great to get rid of this extra method each() altogether but if it works, it works. Thank you!

Comment: @cheeseus my original code would work if you replace the instances of `$option['value']` with `$option[1]` if you want to rid yourself of the extra each method... but hey, if it works, it works! Might also try moving it to a closure `$each` so it makes less noise as a method within the class.

Answer (score 2):

I went for a foreach starting with a check for the 3rd while loop condition.

```php
$this->html  = array();
$this->items = $this->get_menu_items();

foreach ($this->items as $item)
    $children[$item['parent_id']][] = $item;

// loop will be false if the root has no children (i.e., an empty menu!)
$loop = !empty($children[$root_id]);

// initializing $parent as the root
$parent = $root_id;
$parent_stack = array();

// HTML wrapper for the menu (open)
$this->html[] = '<ul>';
if ($loop) {
    foreach ($children[$parent] as $option) {
        if ($parent > $root_id) {
            break; // exit loop
        }
        if ($option === false) {
            $parent = array_pop($parent_stack);

            // HTML for menu item containing childrens (close)
            $this->html[] = str_repeat("\t", (count($parent_stack) + 1) * 2) . '</ul>';
            $this->html[] = str_repeat("\t", (count($parent_stack) + 1) * 2 - 1) . '</li>';
        } elseif (!empty($children[$option['id']])) {
            $tab = str_repeat("\t", (count($parent_stack) + 1) * 2 - 1);

            // HTML for menu item containing childrens (open)
            $this->html[] = sprintf(
                '%1$s<li><a href="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
                $tab,   // %1$s = tabulation
                $option['link'],   // %2$s = link (URL)
                $option['title']   // %3$s = title
            );
            $this->html[] = $tab . "\t" . '<ul class="submenu">';

            array_push($parent_stack, $option['parent_id']);
            $parent = $option['id'];
        } else
            // HTML for menu item with no children (aka "leaf") 
            $this->html[] = sprintf(
                '%1$s<li><a href="%2$s">%3$s</a></li>',
                str_repeat("\t", (count($parent_stack) + 1) * 2 - 1),   // %1$s = tabulation
                $option['link'],   // %2$s = link (URL)
                $option['title']   // %3$s = title
            );
    }

    // HTML wrapper for the menu (close)
    $this->html[] = '</ul>';

    return implode("\r\n", $this->html);
}
```

Tested with:

```php
[ 
    ['id'=>1, 'parent_id'=>0, 'title'=>'title 1','link'=>'link 1','position'=>'0'],
    ['id'=>2, 'parent_id'=>1, 'title'=>'title 2','link'=>'link 2','position'=>'0'],
    ['id'=>3, 'parent_id'=>1, 'title'=>'title 3','link'=>'link 3','position'=>'0'],
    ['id'=>4, 'parent_id'=>0, 'title'=>'title 4','link'=>'link 4','position'=>'0'],
];
```

Comment: I replaced everything in the function from `while (...)` down until the end but I get the same notices as below.

Comment: Running that code in the sandbox from below, removing the `['value']` from array properties fixed the index error, the values or `values` are stored in the array. Updated answer

Comment: I copy-pasted and edited this to use my DB – very simple substitution of some of the indexes – twice, and both times it seems to work (no errors thrown), but the menu list that is generated is cut off at the beginning first submenu: `<ul class="submenu">`. Not sure what is wrong. I will try again tomorrow.

Comment: I've tried again, to the same result: only the main list is generated. I will try to add screenshots to my original post showing what the old code, your code, and @Kevin Y's code produce.

Comment: Please see my original post for a print out of what `get_menu_items($lang)` provides from my database. Perhaps you can test your version with it to find out what the problem is.

Comment: I have now tested your version using the original data, unmodified in any way, and the menu still fails to be generated – ends after printing the first `<ul class="submenu">`.